# Descriptive statistics on values outside of group for each group

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `DataFrame` like this:

**edited**: each `name` can appear multiple times, in any `org`.

```python
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('org_1', 'a', 1),
        ('org_1', 'a', 2),
        ('org_1', 'a', 3),
        ('org_1', 'b', 4),
        ('org_1', 'c', 5),
        ('org_2', 'a', 7),
        ('org_2', 'd', 4),
        ('org_2', 'e', 5),
        ('org_2', 'e', 10)
    ],
    ["org", "name", "value"]
)
```

I would like to calculate for each `org` and `name`: the `mean`, `stddev` and `count` of `values` from the rest of the names excluding that name within each `org`. E.g. For `org_1`, name `b`, `mean = (1+2+3+5)/4`

The DataFrame has ~450 million rows. I cannot use vectorized pandas_UDF because my Spark version is 2.2. There is also a constraint of `spark.driver.maxResultSize` of `4.0 GB`.

I tried this on `Pandas` (filter rows within groups and take mean/std/count) on a `DataFrame` with only two columns (`name` and `value`). I haven't figured out how to do this with two levels of grouped columns (`org` and `name`).

```python
def stats_fun(x):
    return pd.Series({'data_mean': x['value'].mean(),
                      'data_std': x['value'].std(),
                      'data_n': x['value'].count(),
                      'anti_grp_mean': df[df['name'] != x.name]['value'].mean(), 
                      'anti_grp_std': df[df['name'] != x.name]['value'].std(),
                      'anti_grp_n': df[df['name'] != x.name]['value'].count()
                     })
df.groupby('name').apply(stats_fun)
```

Is there a similar UDF function I can define on Spark? (This function would have to take in multiple columns). Otherwise, what is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `UDF` can also work.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = sql.createDataFrame(
[
    ('org_1', 'a', 1),
    ('org_1', 'a', 2),
    ('org_1', 'a', 3),
    ('org_1', 'b', 4),
    ('org_1', 'c', 5),

    ('org_2', 'a', 7),
    ('org_2', 'd', 4),
    ('org_2', 'e', 5),
    ('org_2', 'e', 10)
],
["org", "name", "value"]
                         )

+-----+----+-----+
|  org|name|value|
+-----+----+-----+
|org_1|   a|    1|
|org_1|   a|    2|
|org_1|   a|    3|
|org_1|   b|    4|
|org_1|   c|    5|
|org_2|   a|    7|
|org_2|   d|    4|
|org_2|   e|    5|
|org_2|   e|   10|
+-----+----+-----+
```

After applying `groupby` and collecting all elements in `list`, we apply `udf` to find statistics. After that, columns are exploded and split into multiple columns.

```py
def _find_stats(a,b):
    dict_ = zip(a,b)
    stats = []
    for name in a:
        to_cal = [v for k,v in dict_ if k != name]
        stats.append((name,float(np.mean(to_cal))\
                          ,float(np.std(to_cal))\
                          ,len(to_cal)))
    print stats 
    return stats
find_stats = F.udf(_find_stats,ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))

cols = ['name', 'mean', 'stddev', 'count']
splits = [F.udf(lambda val:val[0],StringType()),\
          F.udf(lambda val:val[1],StringType()),\
          F.udf(lambda val:val[2],StringType()),\
          F.udf(lambda val:val[3],StringType())]

df = df.groupby('org').agg(*[F.collect_list('name').alias('name'), F.collect_list('value').alias('value')])\
       .withColumn('statistics', find_stats(F.col('name'), F.col('value')))\
       .drop('name').drop('value')\
       .select('org', F.explode('statistics').alias('statistics'))\
       .select(['org']+[split_('statistics').alias(col_name) for split_,col_name in zip(splits,cols)])\
       .dropDuplicates()

df.show()

+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+                         
|  org|name|             mean|            stddev|count|
+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
|org_1|   c|              2.5| 1.118033988749895|    4|
|org_2|   e|              5.5|               1.5|    2|
|org_2|   a|6.333333333333333|2.6246692913372702|    3|
|org_2|   d|7.333333333333333|2.0548046676563256|    3|
|org_1|   a|              4.5|               0.5|    2|
|org_1|   b|             2.75| 1.479019945774904|    4|
+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```

If you also want `'value'` column, you can insert that in the tuple in udf function and add one split udf. 
Also, since there will be duplicates in the dataframe due to repetition of names, you can remove them using `dropDuplicates`.

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your edit in question @NaomiHuang

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this using only `DataFrame` functions.

Just join your DataFrame to itself on the `org` column and use a where clause to specify that the `name` column should be different. Then we select the distinct rows of `('l.org', 'l.name', 'r.name', 'r.value')` - essentially, we ignore the `l.value` column because we want to avoid double counting for the same `(org, name)` pair.

For example, this is how you could collect the other values for each `('org', 'name')` pair:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), on='org')\
    .where('l.name != r.name')\
    .select('l.org', 'l.name', 'r.name', 'r.value')\
    .distinct()\
    .groupBy('l.org', 'l.name')\
    .agg(f.collect_list('r.value').alias('other_values'))\
    .show()
#+-----+----+------------+
#|  org|name|other_values|
#+-----+----+------------+
#|org_1|   a|      [4, 5]|
#|org_1|   b|[1, 2, 3, 5]|
#|org_1|   c|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
#|org_2|   a|  [4, 5, 10]|
#|org_2|   d|  [7, 5, 10]|
#|org_2|   e|      [7, 4]|
#+-----+----+------------+
```

For the descriptive stats, you can use the `mean`, `stddev`, and `count` functions from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```python
df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), on='org')\
    .where('l.name != r.name')\
    .select('l.org', 'l.name', 'r.name', 'r.value')\
    .distinct()\
    .groupBy('l.org', 'l.name')\
    .agg(
        f.mean('r.value').alias('mean'),
        f.stddev('r.value').alias('stddev'),
        f.count('r.value').alias('count')
    )\
    .show()
#+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
#|  org|name|             mean|            stddev|count|
#+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
#|org_1|   a|              4.5|0.7071067811865476|    2|
#|org_1|   b|             2.75| 1.707825127659933|    4|
#|org_1|   c|              2.5|1.2909944487358056|    4|
#|org_2|   a|6.333333333333333|3.2145502536643185|    3|
#|org_2|   d|7.333333333333333|2.5166114784235836|    3|
#|org_2|   e|              5.5|2.1213203435596424|    2|
#+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```

Note that [`pyspark.sql.functions.stddev()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.stddev) returns the unbiased sample standard deviation. If you wanted the population standard deviation, use [`pyspark.sql.functions.stddev_pop()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.stddev_pop):

```python
df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), on='org')\
    .where('l.name != r.name')\
    .groupBy('l.org', 'l.name')\
    .agg(
        f.mean('r.value').alias('mean'),
        f.stddev_pop('r.value').alias('stddev'),
        f.count('r.value').alias('count')
    )\
    .show()
#+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
#|  org|name|             mean|            stddev|count|
#+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
#|org_1|   a|              4.5|               0.5|    2|
#|org_1|   b|             2.75| 1.479019945774904|    4|
#|org_1|   c|              2.5| 1.118033988749895|    4|
#|org_2|   a|6.333333333333333|2.6246692913372702|    3|
#|org_2|   d|7.333333333333333|2.0548046676563256|    3|
#|org_2|   e|              5.5|               1.5|    2|
#+-----+----+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```

**EDIT**

As [@NaomiHuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9554721/naomi-huang) mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501604/descriptive-statistics-on-values-outside-of-group-for-each-group/49515665#comment86045666_49515665), you could also reduce `l` to the distinct `org/name` pairs before doing the join:

```python
df.select('org', 'name')\
    .distinct()\
    .alias('l')\
    .join(df.alias('r'), on='org')\
    .where('l.name != r.name')\
    .groupBy('l.org', 'l.name')\
    .agg(f.collect_list('r.value').alias('other_values'))\
    .show()
#+-----+----+------------+
#|  org|name|other_values|
#+-----+----+------------+
#|org_1|   a|      [5, 4]|
#|org_1|   b|[5, 1, 2, 3]|
#|org_1|   c|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
#|org_2|   a|  [4, 5, 10]|
#|org_2|   d|  [7, 5, 10]|
#|org_2|   e|      [7, 4]|
#+-----+----+------------+
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that each `name` can appear in multiple rows (this is log level data) so each row would be matched with all other rows in the same `org` on `join`. In that case you would reduce `l` to one row per `org`/`name` pair first before joining, right?

Comment: @NaomiHuang can you update your question with some representative examples of what you mean?

Comment: @NaomiHuang I have updated my answer to handle your request. You are correct- you need to reduce `l` to the distinct `org/name` pairs. You could do this before the join as your suggested, or after as I have demonstrated here.